# How to open file from vim cscope command output list?

Tags: vim, cscope

i am getting below error while i am tring to open file from output of cscope command

**error detected while processing /etc/vimrc
line 39
cs_read_promt_EOF:Suceess
e609 cscope error:invlib.c:566 invopen:assertion 'invcntl-aram.sizeblk==sizeof(t_logicalblk')failed.**

Comment: What is the cscope command you ran when this error happens? And what does line 39 of your .vimrc file do?

Comment: i ran cs command and. in vimrc     39 line is cs add $PWD/cscope.out

Comment: Are you sure $PWD/cscope.out is a valid path? You could add your own print/check statement right before that line is called to see what path you expect to get.